# How to get a string into an array using vbscript?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have a randomly generated string which is generated at runtime.

I want to capture the value of that string into an array such that

- the first word of the string becomes the first element in the array,
- second word the second element

  and so on.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBscript use the [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp) function:

```
dim myArray, myString
myString = "This is an example"
myArray = Split(myString)
```

Comment: This My array would be the name of the array..Rite?
dim rndstr()
rndstr=split(string)
It shows type mismatch error..

Comment: Remove the parenthesis: dim rndstr   rndstr=split(string) Updating my answer to give a complete example.